# Flutter AID Command

Tags: flutter, nfc

I'm using a flutter_nfc_kit library for NFC communication.

I have a question.

When I use transceive method. ( https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit )

AID doesn't work in android, but READ_AID works.

Do you guys know why AID doesn't work in flutter android?
(I think OS catch AID command, at first, when I send AID command to other NFC Reader)

---

static List **AID** = [0xD2, **0x76**, 0x00, 0x00, 0x85, 0x01, 0x01];
static List **READ_AID** = [0xD2, **0x77**, 0x00, 0x00, 0x85, 0x01, 0x01];

selectAidAppCmd = Uint8List.fromList(APDUCommand.selectApp(APDUCommand.AID));
selectAidAppCmd = await FlutterNfcKit.**transceive(selectAidAppCmd)**;

---